# How to Implemented Knutt Morris Pratt Algorithm in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, string, knuth-morris-pratt

i have trouble understanding this implementation KMP algorithm in laravel
is there a way to implemented KMP Algorithm into laravel app based?

i want to convert this script from native into framework script
i seem cant find anything in google about Knutt Morris Pratt implemented in laravel based

```
`<?php
$c  = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysql_selectdb("web", $c);
 
if(!$db){
    echo "Purchase DB! :p";
    exit();
}
 
include_once("kmp.php");
$kata = '';
if(isset($_GET['word']))
  $kata = $_GET['word'];
 
?>
<div style="width:600px;">
<form method="get" action="">
Find Word : <input type="text" name="word" value="<?php echo $word; ?>" /> <input type="submit" value="Find">
</form>
</div>
<?php
$KMP = new KMP();
 
$art = mysql_query("select * from article");
while($teks = mysql_fetch_array($art)){
 
  if($word!=''){
    $result = $KMP->KMPSearch($word,$text['content']);
 echo "The word you are looking for is : ".$word."<br/>";
 echo "Number of words found : ".count($result)."<br/>";
 echo "That is at the position of the string to : ";
 foreach($result as $h) echo $h." ";
 echo "<br/>";
  }
  echo "<div style='width:600px;'>";
  echo "<h3>".$text['title']."</h3><hr/>";
  echo nl2br(str_replace($word,"<font color='red'>".$word."</font>",$text['content']));
  echo "</div>";
}
?>`
```

i need to use this code because my essay need me to implemented at least 1 algorithm in my web apps and i want to use it for finding string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel uses a structure called [PSR4](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/contributions#coding-style)

Create a folder called Services under app and create a new file, call it KMP.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Services;

class KMP
{
    public static function search($string, $pattern)
    {
        $retVal = array();
        $M = strlen($pattern);
        $N = strlen($string);
        $i = 0;
        $j = 0;
        $lps = array();

        self::computeLPSArray($pattern, $M, $lps);

        while ($i < $N) {
            if ($pattern[$j] == $string[$i]) {
                $j++;
                $i++;
            }

            if ($j == $M) {
                array_push($retVal, $i - $j);
                $j = $lps[$j - 1];
            } elseif ($i < $N && $pattern[$j] != $string[$i]) {
                if ($j != 0) {
                    $j = $lps[$j - 1];
                } else {
                    $i = $i + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        return $retVal;
    }

    private static function computeLPSArray($pattern, $m, &$lps)
    {
        $len = 0;
        $i = 1;

        $lps[0] = 0;

        while ($i < $m) {
            if ($pattern[$i] == $pattern[$len]) {
                $len++;
                $lps[$i] = $len;
                $i++;
            } else {
                if ($len != 0) {
                    $len = $lps[$len - 1];
                } else {
                    $lps[$i] = 0;
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now run `composer du` in your terminal which will dump the autoload file and look for new files.

then you can use it like so.. in your routes for instance

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Services\KMP;

Route::get('/test', function () {
    $data = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    $value = KMP::search($data, "the");
    dd($value);
});
```

Comment: oh it using foreach

Comment: it finally works like a charm, and btw this kmp find a string and tell which position the data that input in but can it be change instead of getting a bunch of string number position, how can i achieve with highlighted text?

Comment: Thats a seperate question with another answer sorry. if this is the one you were after mark it correct (green tick) then ask another question on stack overflow :)